# Change velocity-mirror host from localhost to specific one in client

Tags: meteor, jasmine, mocha.js, velocity

I am in a window 7 and meteor project is under ubuntu server on VirtualBox. So when I install velocity, I've got a problem with localhost in my windows browser. 
http://localhost:5000/?mocha=true&lastModified=1424259562250

> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I want to change localhost to my ubuntu server VirtualBox IP.

Comment: [Related question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796936/how-can-i-get-meteor-client-unit-tests-using-velocity-with-jasmine-to-work-i)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `ROOT_URL` environment variable. This is also true for running the app on a mobile device with Cordova. I found that if my main (not unit-testing) Meteor app was serving up from 192.168.0.222:3000 that my ROOT_URL variable should look like this:

`ROOT_URL="http://192.168.0.222:3000"`

I'm using `sanjo:jasmine` with velocity and with that I can tell you that it uses different ports for client and server unit test servers and that the 3000 in the ROOT_URL variable will get changed to the appropriate ports but it will use the 192.168.0.222 host IP.